# Is there an algorithm that puts elements with equal keys in groups faster than sorting the elements?

Tags: arrays, sorting

Some elements with integer keys are in an array. I want the elements with equal keys to be in groups inside the array. This can be accomplished by sorting the elements, however, it does not matter to me whether the elements are sorted, only that they are in groups of equal keys. Is there a way to accomplish this that is faster than sorting?

Answer (score 0):

A hash map should work well on average. Use a "count" for the value, which gets incremented each time you see the corresponding key in the array, and then use those counts to overwrite your array.

That said, calling "sort" is still pretty fast and easier to read. A good quicksort can actually avoid some work when duplicates exist, so you should really run some benchmarks to be sure that an uglier approach is fast enough to be worthwhile.